# split function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I think I am asking a rather trivial question but I am confused why it isn't working. I have a array inside my lightning component.

```
var records = []
```

This array has values as:

```
~10080%7C,~10081%7C,~10082%7C
```

I want to remove the comma from the above array so my final array will be as follows

```
~10080%7C~10081%7C~10082%7C
```

I tried:

```
var str = records.split(",");
```

I am getting an error saying "split is not a function". Please let me know.

Comment: Nice Question Edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's already an array, you can't split it (you can split a String). I think you mean to `join` it instead:

```
var str = records.join('')
```

Which would result in the output you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, this worked...

Comment: ~10080%7C~10081%7C~10082%7C , this worked